# https webserver react-native

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, https

I was able to set up an HTTP webserver using react-native-http-bridge, on android.
But when I was trying to convert it to **HTTPS** server using BKS which was self-signed with PKCS #12 certificate.

I'm getting a handshake error when trying to request through,
`curl --insecure https://192.168.12.199:8080/some-path`

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but it seems more desirable to upload your server directly to a server like Amazon. If you intend to use https...

Comment: The main goal is to run an HTTPS server in an android device in order to receive data from a custom device